# How to fix, Can't press Ctrl+Alt+Up(Down) for duplicate line in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard

My eclipse preferences > general > keys set duplicate line already, I use On-Screen Keyboard, it's works fine.

But Can't press Ctrl+Alt+Up(Down) doesn't work, How to fix it.

Comment: The shortcut probably conflicts with a shortcut of your system or a tool installed. On Windows, this shortcut is often used by graphic drivers/settings.

Comment: Just so it's clear, what does "doesn't work" mean?  Does it appear to do absolutely nothing (even outside of Eclipse), or does it do something unexpected? Even though you say it's already set in your keys preferences, can you edit that again and enter the same key binding?  I would think if the OS is taking that key binding (what @howlger refers to), it wouldn't let you enter that key binding.

Comment: This is a problem related with remote desktop.
https://superuser.com/questions/327866/remote-desktop-sending-ctrl-alt-left-arrow-ctrl-alt-right-arrow-to-the-remote-p